Deamons de Docker en Jenkins aparentemente no funcionan
estoy incursionando en tema Jenkins con el objetivo de dejar programados test hechos sobre con Playwright.
Instalé Jenkins en mi maquina y generé un proyecto pipeline poniendo en un principio el pipeline que figura en la doc de Playwright:
   agent { docker { image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.46.0-jammy' } }
   stages {
      stage('e2e-tests') {
         steps {
            sh 'npm ci'
            sh 'npx playwright test'
         }
      }
   }
}

Al hacer el "Build" me da este error y no estoy encontrando datos al respecto en internet.
15:32:57  error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.46/containers/mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.44.1-jammy/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

